# How to change stroke width in Pygal

Tags: python, pygal

In Pygal, is there a way to change the stroke width (make it thicker for example)?

I didn't find anything related to that in the docs.

Comment: Maybe you need this setting: http://www.pygal.org/en/latest/api/pygal.config.html?highlight=stroke_style#pygal.config.Config.width

Answer (score 0):

There is a `to_dict` method on the `Style` class that is very helpful for creating custom styles.

```
>>> CleanStyle.to_dict()
{'opacity': '.8', 'foreground': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)', 'plot_background': 'rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.7)', 'stroke_style': 'round', 'foreground_light': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)', 'transition': '250ms', 'foreground_dark': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', 'stroke_dasharray': '0,0', 'opacity_hover': '.9', 'stroke_width': 1.0, 'colors': ('rgb(12,55,149)', 'rgb(117,38,65)', 'rgb(228,127,0)', 'rgb(159,170,0)', 'rgb(149,12,12)'), 'background': 'transparent', 'font_family': 'monospace'}
```

Here's how you might create a custom style with a thick stroke width.

```
>>> from pygal.style import Style, CleanStyle
>>> style_arg = CleanStyle.to_dict()
>>> style_arg['stroke_width']=10
>>> HeavyCleanStyle = Style(**style_arg)
>>> HeavyCleanStyle.to_dict()
{'opacity': '.8', 'foreground': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)', 'plot_background': 'rgba(240, 240, 240, 0.7)', 'stroke_style': 'round', 'foreground_light': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9)', 'transition': '250ms', 'foreground_dark': 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', 'stroke_dasharray': '0,0', 'opacity_hover': '.9', 'stroke_width': 10.0, 'colors': ('rgb(12,55,149)', 'rgb(117,38,65)', 'rgb(228,127,0)', 'rgb(159,170,0)', 'rgb(149,12,12)'), 'background': 'transparent', 'font_family': 'monospace'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following on `stroke_style`

```
chart.add("Title", [], stroke_style={'width': 5})
```